# Oracle Rman recovery to another database on different location

Tags: oracle, backup, recovery, rman

We had production user facing data loss from production Oracle database and only wanted to recover just one schema in the  test database from a week ago. Backup team was able to retrieve the physical files for pfile, control files, redo logs and dbf files , undo.dbf. And all files copied into a location at the test server E drive (which is different file structure from production). I found an empty unused database in test server where I can use for recovery. Just checking (after reading a lot of articles online and different ways) what are best approach.

I roughly draft the steps like below

1. Amend the current pfile and startup no mount
2. restore the controlfile with the current control file from prod
3. startup mount
4. using RMAN to set new name or using RMAN copy datafile to new location, switch datafile to copy
5. open database, and do expdp impdp to the schema needed for recovery

Appreciate if anyone can help, as there's too many reference around online, I read but getting confuse

Comment: You don't need an "empty, unused database" for recovery.  An rman restore/recovery actually restores a database in its entirety. The database is nothing but the files (control, data, redo), and rman starts by restoring those from backup.  There is nothing 'tricky' about what you want.  It is nothing more, nothing less, than a simple rman restore and recover operation, as detailed in the Database Backup and Recovery User's Guide.  You don't say what version of DB, but for starters, the 18c version is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/bradv/index.html)  cont ..

Comment: cont ...   Whether or not you need to rename files and or directories  is up to you.  Once you have recovered your database, then yes, you'd follow that up with expdp/impdp to copy the selected schema back to the production version.